# No bean found under attribute key (struts 1.3.10)

Tags: struts-1

I have the following error when try to submit a form:

```
"javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No bean found under attribute key user"
```

These are my files:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.struts1</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>struts1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>
       /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
  <form-beans>
    <form-bean name="user" type="com.struts1.domain.User" />
  </form-beans>
  <action-mappings>
      <action name="user" path="/userInteraction" scope="request" type="com.struts1.controller.UserInteraction" input="/index.jsp">
        <forward name="success" path="/user.jsp" redirect="true" />
      </action>
  </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <html:form action="/userInteraction.do">
        <html:submit value="Send" />
    </html:form>
</body>
```

**user.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello user!</h1>
  <logic:equal name="user" property="firstName" value="evgheni" scope="request">
        User Logged In
  </logic:equal>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UserInteraction.java** (action class)

```
package com.struts1.controller;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import com.struts1.domain.User;
import com.struts1.persistance.UserDAOImpl;
import com.struts1.persistanceI.UserDAO;

public class UserInteraction extends Action{
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl();
    request.setAttribute("user", userDAO.getUser(1));
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

}

**User.java**

```
package com.struts1.domain;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class User extends ActionForm{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int id;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, int id) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }
    // getters and setter go here
}
```

> The `userDAO.getUser(1)` returns a User from DB by its id.
>   The javax.servlet.ServletException error appears after form submitting.

**I'm using tomcat7 container, and Java 8.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception suggests, there is no bean found under attribute key "user", so our area of interest is the mappings in the struts-config file. As I can see you have a proper mapping between the `<action>` and the `<form-bean>` but when the first request is sent to the Action class, there is a forward which takes us to the user.jsp but there is redirect to the user.jsp, which means a new request will be generated by the client for user.jsp, so the request parameters will be lost in the process.

For more details on forward vs redirect please go through this [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).

Just remove the redirect attribute in the forward mapping and your code will work fine.

Comment: Thank you [Priyanshu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2610629/priyanshu) for this clear response!
Finally I have changed `redirect="true"` to `redirect="false"` in order to make just forward not redirect (I want in future to add some more forwards in my Action class).